# One-to-one relationship or NULL field for optional column?

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization, denormalization

I am working on a database design and would like to store user addresses.  Consider the following:  Many times when you register your address with a website there is 'address line 1' and 'address line 2'.

Since 'address line 2' is optional what is the best practice for storing it?

Would you want to use a single table and allow 'address line 2' to be NULL or would you want to create a separate table with a one-to-one relationship?

FYI using MySQL for my database.

Comment: A nullable field. If you add a table for every field that can be null you will have thousands of tables for a small database.

Comment: None of the Above - A non-nullable field that defaults to a single-space. Where you can, avoid the headaches of having to coalesce your nullable fields. to get intuitive Boolean results.

Comment: @juergend's answer is the more accepted approach. One of the things `null` defines is "no value", and that's the case here. Nulls exist for a reason; this is one of them.

Comment: I'd go with the single table and making address 2 as null, easy to maintain all the way. No need to join tables just to query result

Comment: @EdGibbs: While this has been common practice, I argue that a better semantics for NULL, which reduces the need for repetitive typing of Coalescing operations, is "may have value, but not known yet".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pieter Geerkens, about using the main table.

Yet, if your design  **requires meta information** about that extra second line, such as a name label or type-of-second-line such as an enum of "floornum","appartmentnum","buildingnum", that'd be a case for using a second table.

.. but otherwise, store in main table.  And if you do, my answer is use a `NULL` value. That is the standard default when *absolutely* nothing is stored

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question.  User-to-address is indeed one-to-many however I am concerned with how an address is structured.  For example line 1 is usually the street and house number, while line two is optional but can be used for things like apartment numbers if one is present.

Comment: @TomPace: Now, display code for the address line must test **both** for the line being null, and for it being all spaces; or constantly coalesce the null to a space in order to perform a simple comparison. Why make a simple task more complex?

Answer (score -1):

None of the Above - A non-nullable field that defaults to a single-space. Where you can, avoid the headaches of having to coalesce your nullable fields. to get intuitive Boolean results

The real reason why it is wrong to create a separate table, in this instance, is that the address label only has room for two address lines. Therefore store the two address lines in the main table.

In other circumstances the maximum number of possible values is truly unknown, so a separate table is (at least theoretically, there can be overriding considerations of practicality) correct.

**Update**:
Note that in this example, the value of *all spaces* is already a special value that must be handled specially - by omission on the printed address label (or other display medium). Adding an additional special value, NULL, with the identical semantics and handling on the printed lable is wasteful ad unnecessary.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the all-spaces special value in the context of a second address line.  Is this a standard practice?  I suppose in the immediate association of database-to-mailmerge, without filtering for NULL, there could be problems.

Comment: @TomPace: How often do you see a blank line between the street address and the city/state line? The postoffice automated sorting can even get confused by this. If a blank line is needed to vertically align the address, it should appear at the top rather than in the middle of the address. P.S. I **never** trust programs to implicitly handle my NULL's properly. If the handling advertised in the documentation is not exactly what I want, I coalesce to an appropriate value.

Comment: You sound like you have much familiarity with the printed format, but I don't.  Yet I have plenty of experience with it in display, and it's trivial to consider either case.  There was no case for print given, and even so, the asker's pre-conceived ideas gave no indication of blank line as a third option. I did agree with you about the main-table point, as the asker suggested.

Comment: @TomPace: This example is indeed trivial. Yet **every** use of a nullable field in a database design introduces another instance where Modal Logic must be considered in the construction of Boolean conditions, with consequent loss of the Excluded Middle assumption that we all take for granted in our thinking. I get tired of typing all those coalesce operations where there was no need to force their use.

Comment: @TomPace: And most junior programmers now seem never to have even heard of the Excluded Middle, and why it is important when writing Boolean conditions. Every NULL I can keep out of their hands is another bug-creation opportunity avoided.

Comment: I had planned to learn more about your perspective, the reason you argue strongly against NULL.  I do respect your frustration at your design preference being thumb-downed, and I can see your point against NULL, but for the sake of delivering a simplified accessible answer (which is generally what junior programmers need), I went with the standard.  If the asker reads this discussion and accepts your answer, that'd be fine by me.